# My variable in not getting reset on every other request - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I've setup a project using [Typescript-Node-Starter](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter) I've created a controller and a route to call the function

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import axios from "axios";
import { parseString } from "xml2js";


let box = 0;

export const index =  (req: Request, res: Response) => {     
     box++;
     res.send(JSON.stringify(box));
};
```

I start server with `npm run watch-node`

Then I hit the URL on browser to execute above function
`http://localhost:3000/upwork`
it prints 1 and then when I keeps refreshing it keeps on adding 1 into the last value of the box variable.

I am surprised to see that variable is not refreshing. Why is it not resetting on every request ?

Comment: Why would it? It's defined outside of the request handler, so it exists in the global [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in the comments, you have declared the variable in a global scope, meaning that the same variable is used in each request. If you do not want this behaviour, declare the variable as a local variable inside the function:

```
export const index =  (req: Request, res: Response) => {   
    let box = 0;  
    box++;
    res.send(JSON.stringify(box));
};
```